# Prevent form reload in QWebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, qt4

I am submitting a form async. Thus I do not want the page to reload and thus placed a `preventDefault` call in the handler, but it still reloads the page on submit.
As far as I read other topics this should have been sufficient to disable page reload, but obviously, I am missing something.

```
$( "#loginForm" ).submit( function( event ) {

    try {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Some async handling
    } catch( ex ) {
        alert( ex );
    }
    return false;

} );
```

Could someone point out the problem in my approach?
The whole thing is happening inside a `QtWebkit` Control.

**EDIT:**

Now also tried:

```
$( "#submitButton" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    try {
        // Some async handling
    } catch( ex ) {
        alert( ex );
    }
    return false;
} );
```

With no different result.

Comment: Is your handler running at all?

Comment: Are you waiting for DOM ready?

Comment: @SLaks yes, login works fine.

Comment: @roasted I register this in `window.onload`

Comment: have you tried `$('#submitBtn').on('click', function(event){...})`? instead of handling this on the form submit

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat That leads to a hacky solution. Not what I was looking for :(

Comment: Do you get inside of that handler at all? Put debugger; there and check.

Comment: @ADNow I get inside the handler just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Both `return false;` and `event.preventDefault();` working as intended. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Px5df/2/). There is perhaps something wrong with your event handler.

```
$( "#loginForm" ).submit( function( event ) {
    try {
        // Some async handling
    } catch( ex ) {
        alert( ex );
    }

    event.preventDefault();  // or return false;
} );
```

Comment: The event handler seems to be find, since alert is not triggered. It does not work though.

Comment: I think I don't understand your issue. If you try the Fiddle in the post above (http://jsfiddle.net/Px5df/2/) you'll see that it works. If you delete the line with event.preventDefault(), the form will start to reload again.

Comment: I would have not asked if it was a simple issue ;). There seems to be something other factor at play here. Maybe specific to QtWebkit.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ASP.NET web forms, incidentally? The form ID would be different, not `#loginForm`

Do some processing first, then call `e.preventDefault`, not the other way around, as in Matthias' code.

Also, see [The difference between ‘return false;’ and ‘e.preventDefault()](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)

Comment: Not it is a normal web page.

Answer (score 0):

try seeing if the loginForm submit event is being caught:

```
$( "#loginForm" ).submit( function( event ) {
    alert('submit event fired');
});
```

If it is firing then try this:

```
$( "#loginForm" ).submit( function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
        //do something in here
        // Some async handling
    } catch( ex ) {
        alert( ex );
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Tried, still does reload :(

Answer (score 0):

If the #loginForm is referring to the form itself (not the submit input), then that's your problem. Point the event towards the submit input itself. If this fails, change the input submit to a button and that should definitely work.

Edit:

Change the input submit button to:

```
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

This way there is no default to prevent as it is not a form input submit. This button will never reload the page. Then you just need to attach a click event to the `#submitButton`